# Compiler Magic: Why?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction

I just noticed that given the following code:

```
if (x.ID > 0 && !x.IsCool)
```

the Microsoft C# 3.0 (VS2008 SP1) compiler will optimize it to this:

```
if (!((x.Id <= 0) || x. IsCool))
```

This is on Debug build *without* Optimization enabled. Why does the compiler do that? Is it faster in terms of execution?

I used Reflector to find that out (I was actually looking for something different)

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: And what happens with a side-effect inducing getter? :)

Comment: @pst: side-effects on getters may be ignored by the compiler. Basically, the compiler is allowed to assume no side-effects on getters and setters.

Comment: @Konrad, can you cite spec?  I don't like foisting 'burden of proof' on you, but that sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: @Brian: sorry, no. :-( I always meant to look that up. But I *do* know that the Visual Studio debugger relies on the side-effect freeness of properties. Just try out to debug a code where properties have side-effects, and then look at the value of a property in the watch window (or quick watch) several times. This has already destroyed invariants in my code during debugging.

Comment: @Brian: §17.6.2 only mentions that side-effects in accessors are considered “bad practice”. That doesn’t sound normative. Unfortunately, I’m now unable to find the relevant section in the CLI specification.

Comment: Ok, Konrad, I am 99% sure you are wrong, but I also don't have spec to cite right now.  Compilers are not allowed to futz with the semantics of your program.
A debugger, on the other hand, plays free reign.  The debugger does this not because it is "legal" (you can, after all, just go and poke new values into any variable in the debugger), but because it is useful/convenient.  A debugged program has no expectation of behaving the same as a program without a debugger.  But the compiler has no such luxury to play fast and loose.

Comment: @pst:  Doesn't matter; the getter will be called if and only if x.ID > 0 in either case.

Comment: @Brian: I respectfully disagree. If the debugger creates behaviour different from an (optimizing) build, all hell is allowed to break loose. No spec would wilfully allow this, and no halfway sane debugger implementer either. As for compilers messing with side-effects: it’s completely acceptable and normal to elide side-effects in such circumstances. For example, the C++ specs explicitly allow the compiler to elide copy construction under certain circumstances, and C++ allows considerably less than modern compilers with regards to re-ordering expressions equivalently.

Comment: @Konrad: But the *debugger* isn't creating different behavior, your *interaction* using the debugger is creating different behavior.  Maybe it's just semantics, but I'd argue that once you as a user start touching things in a debugger, there is no guarantee that your program will have identical behavior.  (Classic example: how should code that measures time behave in the presence of breakpoints?)

Comment: (cont’d) furthermore, permitting such optimizations makes a lot of sense, for example to allow optimizing potentially costly computations in loop conditions; consider the imfamous example of the C loop `for (i = 0; i < strlen(somestring); i++)` which must not be optimized unless the compiler *knows* that `strlen` has no side-effects, and `strlen` is expensive. Allowing compilers to omit such repeated calls makes a lot of sense, and for properties it’s entirely risk-free because properties should be side-effect free by design. Bottom line: compilers are absolutely allowed to futz with semantics

Comment: @Daniel: “But the debugger isn't creating different behavior, your interaction using the debugger is creating different behavior.” That’s nitpicking. I’m using the debugger in entirely expected ways, these interactions *must* be supported and yield well-defined, expected (i.e. normed) semantics. Notice that I never *modified* anything, I’m just watching the execution. If the debugger cannot cope with that, it’s useless. Worse, it’s misleading. Sorry, but I won’t budge on this point. Watching code execution must not modify behaviour. Ever. Hint: google “heisenbug” if you don’t know the word.

Comment: Perhaps I'm dense, but what has a side-effect inducing getter to do with anything in this code? Aren't the exact same parts of the expression evaluated, for exactly the same reasons as the original expression, in the same order?

Comment: @Lasse: nothing. The discussion has moved on, creating a huge confusion. An unfortunate consequence of non-threaded comments on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok, thanks, I was straining my nuggin here trying to wrap it around the problem :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The C# compiler certainly **does not generate an equivalent C# code for your snippet**. It's compiled down to IL. Basically, what you are seeing (from Reflector, I guess) is the equivalent C# code that a **decompiler** spits out for that IL.

1. The language specification does not say what an "unoptimized" code is. The C# compiler is allowed to generate any valid, functionally equivalent code. Even without optimization switch on, the compiler might do basic optimizations. Beside that, you can't say *what is **natural** for the compiler* and *whether the compiler deliberately optimized it or not*.
2. The `if` statement as a whole is evaluated as a sequence of conditional branches based on the values of each individual expression specified in the "and" clause. The expression is *not* evaluated in a single code block with "and" instructions. The output of the decompiler is something inferred from those branches. The decompiler cannot always infer the original expression you wrote. It just outputs something equivalent.

Similarly, the difference between this snippet:

```
if (a) { something(); }
else { somethingElse(); }
```

and this snippet:

```
if (!a) { somethingElse(); }
else { something(); }
```

is not something you'd distinguish by seeing the compiled code.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer and succinctly explained to boot. :)

Comment: I wanted to no if this actually is an "optimization" (hence the quotes).

It's the || values together that I was wondering about. I thought IL would use real boolean or/and operations, but this is not the case. under the hood only a combination of ble.s, br.s and brtrue.s is used.

Answer (score 8):

I think these two expressions are exactly equivalent from a language semantics point of view.  Both ways involve short-circuiting.

I am kind of flabbergasted that Andrew's answer already has ten upvotes; it sounds like nonsense to me, but perhaps I really am missing something subtle here.

EDIT

So just to sum up:

The OP's question asks "why does this optimization happen".

In fact there's no 'optimization' happening.  The two C# source codes are logically equivalent.  ".Net Reflector" or whatever other disassembly tool is perhaps as likely to decompile the same IL into one or the other.  At the IL level, there's just a bunch of conditional jumps, and so there's not necessarily a way to know "which way is if and which is else" or other similar DeMorgan equivalences.

Fascinatingly, people are wildly happy to vote up or down answers to this question, even when (or perhaps because) the original question does not make much sense (or relies on a faulty assumption).

Happily, eventually the wisdom of the crowds (and smart individuals like @Mehrdad) prevails.  Hurray for StackOverflow!

(I am making my answer a wiki, because I don't want rep for "storytelling about a question" when rep should be awarded to "good answers to a question".  But I think the story of this question is interesting.)

Comment: @Brian - I was flabbergasted as well considering the fact that I was 100% incorrect :)  That is what I get for posting off-the-cuff like that without thinking.

Comment: You’re absolutely right, a case differentiation reveals that the **exact same** branches are generated by both codes, hence the same short-circuiting. However, this is subtle and on first sight I actually thought that Andrew was right (then I did all the cases in my head).

Comment: :) I am glad that the design of StackOverflow (editing, wiki style, voting) means that eventually everything works out, even if it can be a rollercoaster ride during the first few minutes of a question.  :)

Answer (score 6):

The if compiles to a conditional jump opcode. Lifting the negation out of the expression allows it to be optimized out by swapping the conditional jump target with the fall through block.